# UniSwapV3 mint new position returned unexpected value

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I’m working on a project calling UniSwap V3 contracts. I’ve read the whitepaper, docs and everything I can find online to solve this problem, but get nothing. So I’m here to seek help, not only to solve the problem itself but to fully understand where I miss in the documentations.

First thing is initializing the pool. When I tried to mint a new position I found the comments on the function min() stating:

```
    /// @notice Creates a new position wrapped in a NFT
    /// @dev Call this when the pool does exist and is initialized. Note that if the pool is created but not initialized
    /// a method does not exist, i.e. the pool is assumed to be initialized.
    /// @param params The params necessary to mint a position, encoded as `MintParams` in calldata
    /// @return tokenId The ID of the token that represents the minted position
    /// @return liquidity The amount of liquidity for this position
    /// @return amount0 The amount of token0
    /// @return amount1 The amount of token1
    function mint(MintParams calldata params)
        external
        payable
        returns (
            uint256 tokenId,
            uint128 liquidity,
            uint256 amount0,
            uint256 amount1
        );
```

However, there’s nowhere in the docs to find how I should initialize this pool. Luckily enough, I found a github project demonstrating this feature:

```
        // Creates the new pool
        pool = IUniswapV3Pool(
            v3Factory.createPool(address(token0), address(token1), fee)
        );


        /*
            Calculates the initial price (in sqrtPriceX96 format)
            https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/fetching-prices
            sqrtPriceX96 = sqrt(price) * 2 ** 96
        */
        // Lets set the price to be 1000 token0 = 1 token1
        uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = encodePriceSqrt(1, 1000);
        pool.initialize(sqrtPriceX96);
```

However, when I used this code to initialize the pool, it never worked out as expected. I’ll explain how.

The intended function is to send a pair of n ETH and m MING to the Uniswap. Here’s how I implement it:

```
            pool = IUniswapV3Pool(
                v3Factory.createPool(Address.WETH, addressOfMing, fee)
            );


            // for testing purpose 
            // only 1 to 1 worked. 
            // uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = encodePriceSqrt(1, 1);
            uint160 sqrtPriceX96 = encodePriceSqrt(amountOfMing, amountOfETH);


            pool.initialize(sqrtPriceX96);
            tickSpacing = pool.tickSpacing();


            (uint256 _tokenId, , , ) = 
                mintNewPosition(amountOfETH, amountOfMing);
```

Here’s the implementation of mintNewPosition():

```
        IERC20 ming = IERC20(addressOfMing);


        console.log("amount to mint new position: %s -> %s", amountOfETH, amountOfMing);


        require(
            ming.balanceOf(address(this)) >= amountOfMing, 
            "insufficient Ming"
        );


        require(
            weth.balanceOf(address(this)) >= amountOfETH,
            "insufficient WETH"
        );


        // Approve the position manager
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(Address.WETH, address(nonfungiblePositionManager), amountOfETH);
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(addressOfMing, address(nonfungiblePositionManager), amountOfMing);


        // Get tick spacing
        (, int24 curTick, , , , , ) = pool.slot0();
        curTick = curTick - (curTick % tickSpacing);
        int24 lowerTick = curTick - (tickSpacing * 2);
        int24 upperTick = curTick + (tickSpacing * 2);
        require(curTick % tickSpacing == 0, 'tick error');


        INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams memory params =
            INonfungiblePositionManager.MintParams({
                token0: pool.token0(),
                token1: pool.token1(),
                fee: poolFee,
                tickLower: lowerTick,
                tickUpper: upperTick,
                amount0Desired: amountOfETH, 
                amount1Desired: amountOfMing, 
                amount0Min: 0,
                amount1Min: 0,
                recipient: address(this),
                deadline: block.timestamp
            });


        // Note that the pool defined by DAI/USDC and fee tier 0.3% must already be 
        // created and initialized in order to mint
        (tokenId, liquidity, amount0, amount1) = nonfungiblePositionManager.mint(params);
        console.log("new position minted: %s, %s", amount0, amount1);
```

To my understanding, when I called pool.initialize(sqrtPriceX96), it decided the price of MING regarding ETH. Therefore, upon calling mint() using the same amount of ETH/MING pair, the amount of ETH/MING returned should be the same as there’s no slippages in this process.

However, this is what I got:

```
amount to mint new position: 3000000000000000000 -> 222222222222222000000000000000000
new position minted:         3000000000000000000, 25559352082992436084
```

Did I do anything wrong?